# How to turn my function returns an array in C?(code to fix)

Tags: arrays, c, function

I am trying to make an array store each number I type in.

Some like:
**Enter number:687544**

And return as an array like:
**6 8 7 5 4 4**

I only figure out how to store the nums in order in the "store (num) " function below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int store(int num);

int main()
{
    int num;

    printf("Enter number: ");

    scanf("%d",&num);    

    return store(num);
}

int store(int num)
{   
    if(num!= 0)
    {
        int mod = num % 10;  //split last digit from number

        store(num/10);  //recuring it back to the right order

        printf("%i\n",mod); //divide num by 10. num /= 10 also a valid one 
    }
}
```

Following is I tried but not working code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int store(int num);

int main()
{
    int num,d;
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    for(d=0; num<0;d++);
    {
        num /= 10;
    }

    int a[d];

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<d;i++){
        a[d]=store(num);
    }

    printf("%d \n",a[d]);
}

int store(int num)
{   
    if(num!= 0)
    {
        int mod = num % 10;  

        store(num/10);  

        return mod;
    }
}
```

Unexpected Result.......

```
Enter number: 123

115183680
```

Feel like I almost there but I have no idea which part goes wrong. May I ask how to fix this?

I only figure out how to store the nums in order in the "store (num) " function, however I tried the to expand my code that the result is not I expected.

Comment: In your second code block you probably do not want a semicolon at the end of the for loop `for(d=0; num<0;d++);`

Comment: Do you have to read the number as an int, and not as a string?

Comment: You code has many mistakes, step by step, line int a[d]; is not correct, you can not dynamically allocate in c; second d is the length, if you want to print last index in your last line of the main you should print d-1

Comment: Also when in first loop you count digits to store in d, you already changed num without backing it up, so next you are dealing with corrupted num.

Comment: updated your code to work check each section and above comments to see what are the reasons for each change,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modifed version with comments on what I changed

```
int store(int num, int digit);

int a[20];  // Don't bother with dynamic allocation

int main()
{
    int num,d;
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    int digit = 0;
    int i;
    digit = store(num, 0);

    // Always print at least 1 digit
    for(i=0; i< (digit ? digit : 1); i++){
        printf(" %d", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// Pass in which digit you are on
int store(int num, int digit)
{   
    if(num!= 0)
    {
        int mod = num % 10;
        int last = store(num/10, digit+1);  // next digit

        // Fill array right-to-left
        a[last - digit - 1] = mod;

        return last;
    }
    return digit;  // return number of digits
}
```

Output

```
prog$ ./foo
Enter number: 0
 0
prog$ ./foo
Enter number: 5
 5
prog$ ./foo
Enter number: 123
 1 2 3
```

Note that if you don't want a global array, you can add it as a third parameter to `store`.  Don't forget to initialize `a[0]` in main in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is you code fixed, based on the same routing you have wrote, (using recursive calls) and reading int and parsing digits, etc

```
#include<stdio.h>
 
void store(int num, int* a, int* d);
int main()
{
     int a[10]; // int is 32bit, (Depending on compiler, you can not store more than 10 digit) log10(2**32) ~ 9.xx
     int num,d = 0;
     printf("Enter number: ");
     scanf("%d",&num);
     // the recursive function, should need the pointer to array, and the index which is currently parsing
     store(num, a, &d);
     
     // print your array till valid index,
     for(int i = 0; i< d; i++)
         printf("%d ",a[i]);
     printf("\n");
 }   
void store(int num, int* a, int* d)
{    
     if(num!= 0)
     {
         store(num/10, a, d);
         int mod = num % 10; 
         a[(*d)++] = mod;
     }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to run it in the compiler but no value returned.

Comment: @Dorissss What do you mean it does not return any value? it will print the array at end, but if you need the array to use in different function, array  "a" is the one you need. after line store(num, a, &d) array a is populated with numbers which you need.

Comment: `for(int i; i< d; i++)` fails to initialize `i`

Comment: @stark you are absolutely right, typo fixed, I just edited the original written code by the question and made this typo !